# Find the fundamental group of torus with two points removed

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I'm trying to find a fundamental group of  Torus \ {two points}. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you see what the answer should be and just have trouble proving it?  Or are you having trouble seeing what the answer should be?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury  I know how to find fundamental group of torus with an one point removed, but I have trouble seeing what the answer should be..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you see that if you remove two points from the torus, that the resulting topological space $X$ deformation retracts to the wedge of three circles?  It follows that the fundamental group is the free group on three generators, $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I can see if i remove one points from the torus, then it'll be eight-figure. but I can't see anything when i remove two points...

Comment: Oh i see  now. Thanks!!!